# Why is nodejs saying the port is in use?

Tags: node.js, lsof

I have the following node.js server:

```
const main = () => {
  log(`Starting server`)

  const exit = signal => {
    server.close(() => process.exit())
    log('Server is closed.')
  }
 
  const server = http.createServer(handleRequest)
  server.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.HOST, () => log(`Server is listening on ${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PORT}`))

  process.on('SIGING', exit)
  process.on('SIGTERM', exit)
  process.on('uncaughtException', (err, origin) => {
    log(`Process caught unhandled exception: ${err} ${origin}`, 'ERROR')
  })
}
```

When I first run the server, I see:

```
Server is listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
```

(which is expected)

I kill the server with `ctrl-c`

Subsequent attempts to start the server output:

```
[ 2023-05-09T00:29:53.264Z | INFO ] Process caught unhandled exception: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use "8080" uncaughtException ERROR
```

I have tried the following:

- `lsof`
- `netstat`
- `fuser`
- `npx kill-port 8080`
- `brew install htop`
- restarting the computer

specifics:

```
$ sudo lsof -i :8080
$ sudo lsof -t -i :8080
$ sudo lsof -t -i tcp:8080
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:8080
$ sudo lsof -i :8080 -v
$ sudo lsof > ~/temp_lsof.txt
$ sudo lsof -iTCP:8080 -sTCP:LISTEN
$ sudo netstat -tuln | grep 8080
$ sudo netstat -lnp | grep 8080
$ sudo netstat -tanl | grep 8080
$ sudo netstat -anp tcp | grep 8080
```

Each and every one of these commands resulted in *no output whatsoever*.

```
╭ ~/Desktop/my_api (express-postrgesql)
╰ % npx kill-port 8080
Could not kill process on port 8080. No process running on port.

╭ ~/Desktop/my_api (express-postrgesql)
╰ % node server.js
[ 2023-05-09T01:13:24.247Z | INFO ] Starting api server
[ 2023-05-09T01:13:24.249Z | INFO ] Process caught unhandled exception: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use "8080" uncaughtException ERROR
```

I can't seem to find a process listening on port 8080 and yet... node insists something is.  Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Switched the `PORT` in `.env` to `8081` to test (something looks screwy with the fact that the port is in `""`...):

```
╭ ~/Desktop/my_api (express-postrgesql)
╰ % node server.js
[ 2023-05-09T01:17:50.148Z | INFO ] Starting api server
[ 2023-05-09T01:17:50.150Z | INFO ] Server is listening on "127.0.0.1":"8081"
^C

╭ ~/Desktop/my_api (express-postrgesql)
╰ % node server.js
[ 2023-05-09T01:17:59.339Z | INFO ] Starting api server
[ 2023-05-09T01:17:59.341Z | INFO ] Process caught unhandled exception: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use "8081" uncaughtException ERROR

╭ ~/Desktop/my_api (express-postrgesql)
╰ % sudo lsof -i :8081
Password:

╭ ~/Desktop/my_api (express-postrgesql)
╰ %
```

Comment: How exactly did you use `lsof` and what was the result? Did restarting the computer temporarily resolve the issue or not?

Comment: @Phil `lsof -i :8080`, `lsof -t -i tcp:8080` `lsof -i :3000 -v` (all with and without `sudo`) - restarting the computer did not resolve the issue

Comment: Please [edit] your question with what you tried and **what the result was**

Comment: The clue is in your logging. You appear to have quote characters (ie `"`) embedded in your environment variables. How are they defined?

Comment: Your server says 8081, your kill says 8080.

Comment: @Phil good question - if I define them inline in the server file (`process.env.PORT = "8080"`) (note the quotes) - my logs show `server is listening on 127.0.0.1:8080` (note the _lack_ of quotes).  If I define them in my `.env` file (`process.env.PORT = "8080"`) then read them in manually, I get `server is listening on "127.0.0.1":"8080"`...

Comment: The format of `.env` does not require quotes or spaces but if you're using `dotenv`, it usually handles them ok. How are you loading the `.env` file?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in how I was creating the environment variables, specifically `process.env.PORT`.  Big thanks to @Phil for his helpful questions.

If I say `process.env.PORT = "8080"` *inside* my server file, everything works ok.  I mistook this to mean that I had to wrap my env variables in quotes when inside `.env`:

```
PORT="8080"
```

(Note - none of my other env variables in `.env` were wrapped in quotes, but I wasn't paying attention to those when I added `HOST` and `PORT` to `.env`)

When I read the env variables from `.env` via:

```
const dotEnv = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '.env'), 'utf8')
dotEnv.split('\n').forEach(line => {
  const [ key, val ] = line.split('=')
  process.env[key] = val
})
```

`HOST` was wrapped in extra quotes.

I don't even really know how the server started in the first place... tbd on what `server.listen("127.0.0.1", "8080", ...)` does

---

EDIT

RE "what happens if I pass a string to `server.listen()`?

- firstly, it appears that I am *always* passing a `string` to `server.listen()`.
- in the case of specifying `process.env.PORT = "8080"` in the server file itself, I was, somewhat obviously, setting `process.env.PORT` to a `string` - the string `8080`
- in the case of specifying `process.env.PORT="8080"` in my `.env` file, when I read the variable from the `.env` file to `process.env`, I read it as a `string` as well - the string `"8080"`
- I was under the impression that `server.listen()` performs `parseInt()` on the params expecting numbers - in the case of the string `8080`, `parseInt()` works fine.
- `parseInt("8080")` returns `NaN`

NOW: I am under the impression that if a non-parsable string is passed to `server.listen()`, something should... not work.  But I still saw the logged statements from `server.listen()`'s callback:

```
  server.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.HOST, e => {
    if (e) {
      log(`server.listen() returned error: `, e, process.env.PORT)
      return
    }
    log(`Server is listening on ${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PORT}`)
  })
```

```
[ 2023-05-09T04:09:18.211Z | INFO ] Server is listening on 127.0.0.1:"8080"
```

Per [node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#serverlisten), `The last parameter callback will be added as a listener for the 'listening' event.` - so the server does seem to be "listening".

I will find out:

1. *to what* is the server "listening" (currently I'm only logging the value I passed in, which may differ from the value it ended up as?
2. whatever port "8080" is - why is it not opened up after `ctrl-c` kills the server?
3. if in fact `server.listen()` performs `parseInt()` on the arguments, resulting on a `NaN`, why doesn't `server.listen()` return an error?

---

EDIT

when loading the erroneously double-double quoted PORT from .env (`PORT="8080"`), inspecting the server object in `server.listen()`'s callback shows the following:

```
server.address()  // '"8080"'
server.listening  // true
```

(so to question 3. above, I don't think `server.listen()` is being passed `NaN` after all)

HOWEVER, if I correct this in .env (`process.env.PORT=8080`), we get the following:

```
server.address()  // { address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 8080 }
server.listening  // true
```

`address()` has the shape described in [Net server.address() docs](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#serveraddress).

---

Also note:

if `.env` contains `PORT=8080`, in my server file, `typeof process.env.PORT` is `string` (it just so happens to be a `string` that could be coerced into an integer)

If I say, explicitly, `server.listen('fake', ...)`, `server.listen()` "works" and `server.address()` is `'fake'`

Comment: Yikes, just use [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)