# What happens if I pass server.listen() a string for a port?

Tags: node.js, server, port

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76205312/5221310) answer for context: basically, what if I accidentally set `process.env.PORT` to the string `"8080"` instead of the string `8080`, before calling `server.listen(process.env.PORT, ...)`?

Does `server.listen()` perform any type conversion on its arguments?

What is the meaning of

```
server.address()  // '"8080"'
```

?

What is the server "listening" to if I pass it a string like `server.listen('fake')`?  Inspecting `server.address()` in `server.listen()`'s callback shows `'fake'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [a string is acceptable](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/internal/validators.js#L375).

`server.address()` tells you the address your server is bound to (this is inherited from [the net module](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#serveraddress)).

If you pass a string that can't be coerced into a number that is in a valid port range, this is [an error](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/internal/validators.js#LL389C15-L389C34) depending on how many arguments you passed to `.listen`. The reason for this is that a string *could* be an IPC path. See [the normalization function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/net.js#L270).

Comment: The docs indicate `Check that the port number is not NaN when coerced to a number, is an integer and that it falls within the legal range of port numbers.`  I would think passing the string 'fake' as the `PORT` arg would cause an `ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT` - no?

Comment: @AaronParisi I posted my answer before you edited your question. I just added an answer to that last part of the question.

Comment: Thanks - why then does `server.listen()`'s callback get executed if `server.listen()` throws an error?

Comment: @AaronParis `validatePort` would throw if `'fake'` actually wound up going through that function, but in this example it doesn't, port is set to 0 and `'fake'` is assumed to be [a path](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#identifying-paths-for-ipc-connections). That's what I mean by "depending on how many arguments you've passed" — `.listen()` has a few different signatures and the code that decides which one to use lives in net, not http, so it gets a little hairy.

Comment: Amazing, thanks - any sense why, in this case with the inadvertent path, I can't re-listen on the same path after `ctrl-c`?  I get `EADDRINUSE` even after killing the process (found via `lsof -U`)

Comment: ^ it's because I had a typo - `process.on('SIGING')` instead of `SIGINT` so I didn't handle it like I thought I was lol